# Street neon sign's glow effect

Tags: three.js

Does anyone have any suggestion of how to implement such a light glow effect in Three.js ?

1. There is a TextGeometry mesh
2. Some BoxGeometry mesh as a background

How to make this glow between them?
I tried to put many PointLight between text and box, but after about 20 of PointLights the scene become very slow. I tried to put some RectAreaLights — but the same.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone have any suggestion of how to implement such a light glow effect in Three.js ?

The typical way of doing this is via post-processing. `three.js` offers a so called "Bloom" pass which is demonstrated in the following example: [webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom). I suggest you start with this setup.

> but after about 20 of PointLights the scene become very slow. I tried to put some RectAreaLights — but the same.

It's no good approach in general to add that number of light sources to a `three.js` scene. If you place some small sphere meshes (based on `THREE.SphereGeometry`) with a bright material color onto the text, you should get a good result with bloom pass.

Comment: thank you so much. UnrealBloomPass + MeshStandardMaterial.emissive give me something like that. It's a good start. https://imgur.com/a/YqUaLyO